# jQuery mobile issue only on iOS, when showing movies

Tags: jquery, iphone, video, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a mobile site with jquery mobile, and it works perfect on all platforms without iOS. I've tried to remove the jquery mobile script and then the video loads, but the rest of the page then sucks. It's an mp4 movie.

Using version jquery-mobile-1.0, and video-js.

Anybody with the same problem?

```
<div class="vjs-container">
<div class="videoWidth video-js-box test-css vjs-controls-below vjs-paused" style="width: 1809px;">
    <video height="416" width="720" data-subtitles="/sites/video/PublishingImages/test/test.jpg" poster="" preload="metadata" x-webkit-airplay="allow" class="video-js" tabindex="0" style="">
    <source type="video/mp4; codecs=&quot;avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2&quot;" src="/sites/video/PublishingImages/test/test.mp4"></source>
    <source type="video/ogg; codecs=&quot;theora, vorbis&quot;" src="/sites/video/PublishingImages/test/test.ogv"></source>

        <div class="vjs-flash-fallback">
            <img height="416" width="720" title="Ingen mulighet til å spille av video." alt="Ingen mulighet til å spille av video." src="/Style%20Library/gui/video-fail.jpg">
        </div>
    </video>
    <!-- Download links provided for devices that can't play video in the browser. -->
    <p class="vjs-no-video" style="display: none;">
        <strong>Last ned video:</strong> <a href="/sites/video/PublishingImages/test/test.mp4">MP4</a>,

        <a href="/sites/video/PublishingImages/Oppakning/test.ogv">Ogg</a><br>
        <a href="http://videojs.com">HTML5 Video Player</a> by VideoJS
    </p>
<div class="vjs-styles-check" style="position: absolute; display: none;"></div><img src="http://m.test.aspx" class="vjs-poster" style="display: block; height: 1045px; width: 1809px;"><div class="vjs-big-play-button" style="display: block;"><span></span></div><div class="vjs-spinner"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div><div class="vjs-controls"><div class="vjs-play-control"><span></span></div><div class="vjs-progress-control"><div class="vjs-progress-holder"><div class="vjs-load-progress" style="width: 24.01%;"></div><div class="vjs-play-progress" style="width: 0%;"></div></div></div><div class="vjs-time-control"><span class="vjs-current-time-display">00:00</span><span> / </span><span class="vjs-duration-display">00:00</span></div><div class="vjs-volume-control"><div><span class="vjs-volume-level-on"></span><span class="vjs-volume-level-on"></span><span class="vjs-volume-level-on"></span><span class="vjs-volume-level-on"></span><span class="vjs-volume-level-on"></span><span></span></div></div><div class="vjs-fullscreen-control"><div><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span></div></div></div></div>

<div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd also come across with this problem like the picture shown below, however I'd nailed it
[image: with a mark that says cann't be played]

After 2 days debugging, trials and errors, I took following actions(I suggest you follow, too):

1. upgrade jquerymobile lib to the latest one(version 1.3.1),
   video-js.js(version 4.1.0)
2. get a regular web server(nginx, apache, tomcat...) to serve the video

I would like to clarify that **jquerymobile is working with video-js**.

And explain a little more on **Action 2**

As we can see from the snapshot, there is a mark indicating the video can not be played.
and I've checked the app log, 
[image: clues from app log]

Taking it into account that the video is served by the process running for development env (sort of a toolkit in python, it's **runserver** command from **Django**).

The exception occurred every time I requested a video resource by iPad.
Therefore, I changed the video provider in my system, say nginx, it did work!

The successful snapshot as below:
[image: successful video served by nginx]

Answer (score 1):

Because jQueryMobile loads your page dynamically, you need to use VJS's dynamic setup. You can [read about it in the documentation on their website](http://videojs.com/docs/setup/).

You'll probably want to do this in jQuery's pageInit, like so:

```
$( '#videoPage' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event){
 _V_("example_video_1", {}, function(){
      // Player (this) is initialized and ready.
    });
});
```

Comment: But why does it work on WP7 and Android? This is only a problem in iOS. If this is the only solution I will be having a problem having the same selector on every video.

Comment: Probably a difference in rendering time between the two systems.